# Do out parameters in methods on a stateful object add responsibilities?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have an object that's responsible for sending email, so I create an `EmailSender`, then tell it to `SendEmail`, passing in some `EmailDetails`:

```
string diagnostics;    

EmailSender sender = new EmailSender();
try
{
    sender.SendEmail(details);
    //sender.SendEmail(details, out diagnostics);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    logger.log(sender.CurrentError);
}

diagnostics = sender.Diagnostics;
```

If I add an out parameter to `SendEmail`, does that add a business responsibility in terms of SOLID design principles since I'm now saying: "You must attempt to send an email, and you're also responsible for initializing and populating diagnostic data"

Perhaps responsibility isn't the right word, but is one pattern better than the other?

Comment: `out` parameter is definitely responsiility, at least by C# spec. But what is your question?

Comment: I don't think one approach is better than the other. There's also a third approach, `diagnostics = sender.SendEmail(details);` whch looks more elegant to me than the `out` variant, but it's all just a matter of taste. No definitive answer.

Comment: @sll I'm asking if it adds a business responsibility in terms of SOLID design principles

Comment: In my opinion the method SendEmail is violating SRP.  According to its name, it is meant to send the email, not diagnose any issues.  Let the exceptions bubble up to where they should be caught/handled.

Comment: The line of code `EmailSender sender = new EmailSender();` might violate the "D" part of the SOLID design principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not violating the Single Responsibility Principle - SRP doesn't mean an object shouldn't know how to talk to its collaborators. That's part of its contract, it's a natural responsibility. If `EmailSender` wasn't responsible for reporting diagnostics about the mail delivery, who would be ?

The only thing you need to ensure is that `Diagnostics` remains on a relevant granularity level with regard to `EmailSender`. `EmailSender` doesn't depend on its consumers, consumers depend on `EmailSender`, so `EmailSender` shouldn't adopt the consumers formalism but rather impose its own semantics on them.

Answer (score 1):

You're not violating any of SOLID principles, you're violating so called [Samurai Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SamuraiPrinciple):

> Every operation should either complete their contract and return a valid result, or throw an exception.

If you want provide some additional diagnostics information about failure than add custom exception instead. If you have something that is a part of the contract between you and your client, than you can return this information via output parameter.

Comment: You may interpret adherence to the "Samurai Principle" as also obeying the "Single Responsibility Principle"; code should do one thing. In this case the task is to "send an e-mail". That's the one thing that should happen, and if the method didn't die a horrible death, screaming some relevant empirical knowledge about how it met its untimely end as it happened, the implicit understanding is that it was successful.

Comment: @KeithS Agreed, but this principle is more bright and expressive when we're talking about exception handling.

Comment: Agreed. The comic is also quite illustrative of the primary drawback; when a method told to "succeed or die" and chooses the latter, there are some reasons for "failure" that you'd expect ("didn't have to do anything"), and some you don't ("hard drive exploded"). A method doesn't have to die a horrible death just because it discovered it didn't have anything to do. Usually, finding out there's nothing to do is considered "success"; the system is in the state that the method was told to put it in, regardless of who actually got it there, so the method returns.

Comment: @KeithS In most cases its too hard to distinguish between those kinds of failures and in many cases invalid application configuration or firewall could be treated the same. If not - we have an option here as well: lets use different types of exception with different semantic: one for system failures, another one - for expected logical errors. But silence is not the best choice in most cases.

Comment: Well yes, "send an e-mail" is pretty unambiguous; you "have to", therefore you either can or you can't. but, if you don't "have to" change the visual state of the UI element indicating that it was done, because it's already in the state you would have put it in, then come home "with your shield".

Comment: @KeithS If it is within the realm of responsibility for the method to decide for itself whether or not it should send an email, then I think it is reasonable for that method to also return a Boolean to indicate whether it sent one or not, or perhaps an integer indicating the number of emails sent. Failures would still be exceptions, of course.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice - No arguments there, except perhaps that it ceases to be an "action" and becomes a "function", and theoretically the return value of a function is its primary product. But, that's getting more than a little ivory tower; I've done it exactly that way many times and don't lose a wink of sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code example, I wonder if an AOP design might be appropriate.  You could use Policy Injection to wrap calls to your EmailSender (and other components).

The wrapper that you inject into the call using Policy Injection can be responsible for catching and logging exceptions thrown, so that this code calling `SendEmail` doesn't have to do it.

The wrapper can also be responsible for monitoring timings, writing trace information, etc.  I'm just speculating, but perhaps that sort of information lines up with what you're using your `Diagnostics` property for.

This way, the caller doesn't have to be responsible for handling/logging exceptions, nor with dealing with diagnostic information.  Additionally, the EmailSender doesn't have to be responsible for monitoring its own performance or exposing that information via a `Diagnostics` property.

Also, the `CurrentError` property seems odd. You're already catching an exception, so it seems like it would be more appropriate to catch a specific type of exception that contains whatever information the `CurrentError` property has.